# Selenium Python: Scroll down a specific window (div)

Tags: python, html, selenium, scroll

I'm trying to scroll down a Div inside a website and I've tried almost everything and nothing works. execute_script won't scroll it, actionchains won't work, and with some other methods I've also failed.

This is the website: https://www9.senado.gov.br/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=senado%2Fsigabrasilpainelcidadao.qvw&host=QVS%40www9&anonymous=true&Sheet=SH14

If you click in "Gráficos Customizados" and at the left side there will be a few items to select. If you click on the plus sign of a few items it will expand and a scrollbar will appear. However, I haven't found a way to scroll it down.

These are my selenium options

```
webdriver_manager = importlib.import_module("webdriver_manager.chrome")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={self.__get_user_agent()}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriver_manager.ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
"source":
    "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
    "delete newProto.webdriver;"
    "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
})

params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': self.dir_path}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
```

I've tried this, the element being the scrollbar (and with several others elements inside the table):

```
def wheel_element(element, deltaY = 120, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0):
  error = element._parent.execute_script("""
    var element = arguments[0];
    var deltaY = arguments[1];
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clientX = box.left + (arguments[2] || box.width / 2);
    var clientY = box.top + (arguments[3] || box.height / 2);
    var target = element.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);

    for (var e = target; e; e = e.parentElement) {
      if (e === element) {
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel',     {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY, deltaY: deltaY}));
        return;
      }
    }    
    return "Element is not interactable";
    """, element, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY)
  if error:
    raise WebDriverException(error)    

def scroll_down(driver, element):
    first = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Dimensões e Métricas')]")))
    last = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='QvFrame Document_LB187']//div[@class='QvContent']//div[@class='QvListbox']//div[@class='Qv_ScrollbarHorizontalDivider']")))                                                                                       
    scroll_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='289']/div[2]/div/div[1]")))
    scroll_height = (element.location['y'] - first.location['y']) - ((last.location['y'] - first.location['y']) / 2)
    wheel_element(element, scroll_height)
```

and this:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

and this:

```
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]", element, scroll_height)
```

and ActionChains:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: you should show what did you tried to use. ANd you could create minimal working code which clicks `"Gráficos Customizados"` and click few `plus` to show scrollbar.

Comment: why do you need to scroll? Maybe you should start at the bottom `plus` and maybe you wouldn't have to scroll.

Comment: @furas I already found a work around, but still, it really bothered me not being able to do something so simple as scrolling. I wanted to know how I could do it. And I could send you minimal working code to get to that page, but it is integrated to the code base and is full of wrappers, is pulling several other functions. An option is using driver.get(LINK) time.sleep(120) and select by hand the "Gráficos Customizados" page and see if the scrolling function works.

Comment: `"minimal working code"` means you have to remove all not-important elements and keep only this part which can reproduce problem. I don't ask for full code. If you create `minimal working code` then we have code to test problem and test solutions. Without `minimal working code` we would have to write this minimal code to test solutions - but there are other questions which shows all details and we rather will skip your question.